# What were the spots on the "teddy bear girl" in episode 1?

Tags: the-walking-dead

I just started to watch the first season of *The Walking Dead*. The very first zombie - the "teddy bear girl" - was Rick’s first kill. Why were there blood spots all over the girl? Were they meant to be bullet holes?

[image]

<sup>(from [Interview with Addy Miller - Blastzone Online](https://blastzoneonline.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/interview-with-addy-miller-little-girl-walker-with-the-bunny-slippers-and-teddy-bear-from-the-walking-dead-tv-series-on-amc/))</sup>

Comment: Here is the image of the girl: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=l03WV-SXGcXWmwHQoqLIBQ&q=walking+dead+teddy+bear+girl&btnG=#imgrc=G0e1kj7-R3TWXM%3A  notice the red spots on all over her chest mostly. Looks like she was target practice. Do you think so?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say she must've been crawling around on broken glass, or fell through a window. Either as a survivor trying to get away from zombies, or as a zombie because zombies like that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Without direct word from the show makers at least some speculation has to be what their intention was.

As we can see from the picture some parts of her mouth are missing and blood is still dropping from there. Thus some red spots are from that.

Additionally if we look at it, it does not seem for most of the red spots that there are outright holes in her clothes there (at least not from the picture). So we can assume that many of these spots are mostly from her victims (or if they are intended to be gunshot wounds....then its a small makeup error).

2 round dots without any smearing look at least as if they are at holes in the clothes (1 left, one right on her jacket) and another one on her chest. These COULD represent gun wounds yes.

That is solely from this picture.

If we also take other pictures into account that are shot at a bit more distance we can see that she has quite a lot of holes there in her morning mantle that look like they have holes associated with them. Thus yes it looks like most of these red spots should represent small gun wounds.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. I saw so many bulley holes enough to put down 20 people. She might have just twitched and keeped walking. Someone or a group of people tried to kill before unsuccessfully. The may have tried to shoot her in the head unsuccessfully too

Comment: Would explain the small wound on her head (never got what that should represent, but COULD be a scratch from a barely missed shot)